# Docker compose does not mount

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, yarnpkg

I am trying to do volume mount using docker compose.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  myapp:
    container_name: myapp
    image: myapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: development.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "3005:3005"
      - "5000:5000"
    networks:
      - myapp-network      
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development

networks:
  myapp-network:
    driver: bridge
```

development.dockerfile

```
FROM node:carbon

LABEL Foo bar

ENV CONTAINER_PATH /usr/src/app

WORKDIR $CONTAINER_PATH

EXPOSE 80 443 3005 5000

ENTRYPOINT [ "yarn","start" ]
```

However when I do

```
docker-compose build ===> OK
docker-compose up ===> Throws below error


Attaching to myapp
client       | yarn run v1.5.1
client       | error An unexpected error occurred: "Couldn't find a package.json file in \"/usr/src/app\"".
client       | info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/usr/src/app/yarn-error.log".
client       | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
client exited with code 1
```

The package.json file does exists in current directory i.e. '.' (as per volumes)

Any idea?

Host OS: Windows
Guest OS: node:carbon (linux)

Thanks

Comment: typo: `user` vs `usr` - it should probably be `usr` everywhere

Comment: @nlu good spot. Done that but it still gives same error (with 'usr' folder name) . Question updated.

Comment: whats the content of /usr/src/app in your container? can you change the entrypoint to `["ls"]`

Comment: @JohannesMerz ls gives  "Attaching to myapp
    myapp | yarn-error.log
    myapp exited with code 0." The idea is not to copy the content to guest os but to use volumne to mount so that I can use during development/debug.

Comment: Can you find the `yarn-error.log` file on your (Windows) host? If so you know the volume is mounted correctly in the container. Please verify your `package.json` is also in this same folder.

Comment: "if so you know the volume is mounted correctly in the container" how do you verify this?

Comment: Instead of just `ls`, you want 1. `echo $CONTAINER_PATH` 2.  `ls $CONTAINER_PATH`

Comment: 'ERROR: for myapp  Cannot start service myapp: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"ls /usr/src/app\": stat ls /usr/src/app: no such file or directory": unknown'

Comment: this indicates to me that your volume is not working as it should

Comment: @JohannesMerz My thoughts exactly. But how to fix this!? Its not very clear.